# How to define timestamp value in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, null, timestamp

I have a column of the `timestamp` type. I want to get latest time available for a specific condition and add 1 minute to it. If the condition results in zero records, I get `NULL`. In order to properly operate on it, I need to treat this `NULL` as default/minimal/zero timestamp. And I'm not sure how this can be done in SQL query (not in the field definition). I tried this:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM `table` WHERE false), 0) + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM `table` WHERE false), TIMESTAMP('0000-00-00 00:00:00')) + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM `table` WHERE false), TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

All return `NULL`. Using `TIMESTAMPADD` and UNIX_TIMESTAMP did not get the trick either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember adding timestamp and dates always yields null , even `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + interval 1 minute` returns `NULL`. I guess all you need to do is change `+INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` to `+60` (seconds)

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM `table` WHERE false

To me this seems like a bad statement since "WHERE false" will never return anything (that being NULL)... Are you missing a column like "WHERE column=false"?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
SELECT [whatever] FROM [wherever] WHERE EXISTS([the timestamp query])
```

Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html